Is there a way to do a PhD such that you get a broad view of a field or subfield as a whole?
I will aim to keep this as general as possible, given the already narrow scope of the question.
I am looking for a way to design a PhD around the broader study of mathematics. I want to learn more about the relative relationships of different subjects within math, and am less interested in the arcane outer reaches of a particular subject. I understand that in order to do this successfully, I will probably need to find some lens through which to focus my study. I am curious if there are existing ways that others have managed to do this.
As an example, suppose you are interested in analysis. Rather than study whatever particular problems lie on the periphery of the field, you might focus your research on the particular approach of 19th century mathematicians like Cauchy and Weierstrass. In this way, you've chosen history to be the lens through which you are able to examine the whole (or at least a larger part) of analysis.
Maybe another way to do this is to develop alternative explanations for theorems and/or subjects? It bleeds a bit into pedagogy. Could you direct your PhD research on re-framing traditional explanations in a geometric/visual context? I'm thinking specifically of Visual Complex Analysis and Tristan Needham's idea of the amplitwist. Is it viable to have a thesis that is based on developing/reexamining alternative approaches to understanding math, while still maintaining a rigorous relationship with the mathematical content?
To be clear, I am not speaking specifically about history of math or math education. These are just the only examples I can think of. I am curious if anyone has tried to broaden the scope of their study through other lenses.

I sense a false dichotomy here.

Potentially an interesting question here. I suggested a change to the title to make it clear you are asking about the feasibility of the general approach, rather than "shopping" for a particular PhD institution (the latter would be off-topic here).

"[Y]ou might focus your research on the particular approach of 19th century mathematicians like Cauchy and Weierstrass. In this way, you've chosen history to be the lens through which you are able to examine the whole (or at least a larger part) of analysis." With the aim of doing what? "Developing alternative explanations for theorems" sounds extremely vague tbh. Certainly you will learn a lot if you dive into this kind of investigation. The question is, however, how this will contribute to scientific knowledge above and beyond historical research (which you say you don't want to do).

I understand the urge to contribute to the "big picture" of the field rather than the "small picture", but the point is that it's quite difficult to meaningfully contribute to the big picture without first learning, during the course of your PhD, how to contribute to the small picture (what you call the "arcane outer reaches" but what is actually the bread and butter for most working mathematicians).

@AdamPřenosil First off, apologies for the insulting language. I didn't mean to come across as scornful of actual math research. In grad school I felt ill-equipped to contribute to scientific knowledge and much more adept at re-articulating and explaining already known results. I guess my goal of completing a PhD is to continue to learn and set myself up to become a professor. I am honestly less interested in contributing to scientific knowledge through published research, and more interested in contributing through cogent and engaging teaching. Maybe a PhD is not the place for that?

I did not find your language insulting, just somewhat misleading. Yes, the goal of a PhD is precisely to learn how to "contribute to scientific knowledge through published research". This is not to say that teaching cannot be an equally important or more important way of contributing to science, but learning how to teach undergraduates is not the goal of PhD studies. Though, for better or worse, if teaching math courses is your goal, then my impression is that in practice you need a PhD degree in math anyway, i.e. you need to successfully demonstrate that you can do some research.

Somewhere in a PhD should come some reasonably broad view of a subfield. This is not just some initial 'literature review' but also a natural byproduct of reading the literature. Maybe I read too broadly, but I don't think so - I adopted and incorporated various concepts and experimental techniques that helped me make progress in my specific area.

@AdamPřenosil - Not to mention, most of the big picture stuff has already been pored over by tens of thousands of people... your odds of successfully finding novelty there aren't zero, but they're close to it, and novelty is a fundamental requirement to grant a PhD

I think you can do research like this, but it usually wouldn't be in a math department.
Your two examples fit squarely within math history and math education, respectively. Philosophy of math is another topic where people take a broad view of math and look at it from different lenses. By contrast, to receive a PhD in math, one is generally expected to do new math research, i.e. develop new mathematics that has never been written down before.
There is some wiggle room here. The line between "new mathematics" and "new ways of viewing previously-existing mathematics" is somewhat blurry. But to get a PhD in math, it's expected that your contribution gives some new mathematical insight, in some sense.
One could argue that this segregation between researchers who "do" math and those who "think about" math (for lack of better terms) isn't a perfect state of affairs. We need big picture thinking as well as progress in specific subareas, and modern math academia tends to push people toward the latter.

Thanks for the response. I think that the distinction you make in your last paragraph is essentially what I am struggling with. Do you think it is accurate to differentiate between learning math for the sake of research and learning math for the sake of teaching? If I try to distill my post down into one question, I think it is essentially: If my goal is to understand the breadth of math deeply enough to become an effective teacher to undergraduates, what type of approach should I take?

@ahblay I think that's quite a different question, actually. I know plenty of people who do a great job teaching undergrads despite their research being not big-picture at all. Teaching and research are not COMPLETELY unrelated, but to some extent, they are different skills. I don't think the choice of PhD topic has anything to do with how good a teacher one becomes. You'll certainly understand undergrad-level math well enough to teach it if you graduate from any reputable math PhD program. Understanding the material is absolutely not the hard part of teaching.

And in terms of careers, there are a good number of faculty jobs (particularly at liberal-arts colleges) where teaching is the main focus and research is semi-optional. But to get such jobs, you typically have to do a nontrivial amount of research early in your career.

For what it's worth, "Math Education" is an area of research in the math department in which I'm currently enrolled, and my undergraduate institution had a "History of Mathematics" program (note: had is accurate here --- the singular professor who was in that program has since retired; her PhD was done in a history department).  That is to say, such programs do exist in math departments, though I agree with their rarity.

While you might not be able to find a program like that, you might be able to find an advisor somewhere who meets your needs. But their focus might be more on the history of math or the philosophy of math. Such folks exist.
Doctoral programs, however, in the US, at least, include a breadth component in the initial coursework and the comprehensive exams that give a fairly broad view of the field. Most research, however, following comps is very narrow based as you note. But if you can find an advisor who has a broader view you might be happy enough.
Alternatively, you can get a "typical" doctorate and broaden your view, though you might need to wait to mid career to really do that.
At liberal arts colleges in the US, faculty often take a broader view and it is possibly more acceptable there than at strictly research universities. They need to earn a doctorate (mostly) somewhere, of course.
The path is uncommon, but it is there. You'll have to seek it out.
Let me note that mathematicians seek insight. Insight is what gives you the ability to come up with things that might be true (and significant) but aren't known to be true or false. Insight can be hard to come by and takes work to achieve. One strives for this in a doctoral program. My experience, however, is that mathematical insight isn't general, but can be specific to a subfield. One can, for example, have great insight into, say, abstract algebra, but little if any into topology. This can make your quest difficult. You want more than superficial knowledge of these areas and it can take effort for each of them independently of the others.

Nicely said.  It seems like that's a very cogent argument for a sabbatical.

It is indeed possible to write a Ph.D. thesis providing alternative explanation for theorems -- but to write a good such Ph.D. thesis is much harder than writing one proving new theorems!
A good example is the 1950 thesis of John Tate. Tate's main results were the analytic continuation and functional equation for the Dedekind zeta and Hecke L-functions associated to number fields. (This includes the Riemann zeta function, as a special case.)
The results were already known, but Tate's methods were extremely innovative,
developing an elegant approach in terms of adelic integration and Poisson summation.
Tate's work was enormously influential in the development of modern number theory; almost any working number theorist will be at least broadly familiar with Tate's thesis, and many of them will have read it. It is widely regarded as one of the best Ph.D. theses in math to have ever been written. Tate then went on to have a brilliant career, and advised many students who are now famous number theorists in their own right.
Most of us (including me!) have far more modest talents than Tate. So my advice is to set out and initially try to do something new. That is easier than having new insight into something old. However, if at any point you discover new insights into old methods, by all means pursue them!

I'm not sure about your first paragraph in general. An anecdote doesn't prove a general rule. But, an easy proof of an old result won't likely be innovative enough for publication. Some exceptions apply. And are exciting when they do.

@Buffy I'm saying that it can be done. I'm certainly not saying that an attempt to do something similar will necessarily be successful.
